# Strange Border on UICollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a subclass for a UICollectionViewCell, which looks like this...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class GroupCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subject: UILabel!
}
```

As soon as I override the drawRect function like this...

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
}
```

I get a strange border/shadow on the top and right of each cell (background colour set in storyboard)...

[image: Border on top and right of each cell]

Note that even if I take out the self.layer.cornerRadius line, the borders still appear, so presumably I've missed something out at the drawRect function - I'm just not sure what.

What makes this especially peculiar, is that when I run the code on a iPhone 6+ or wider device, the problem goes away.

The only other (presumably) relevant code, is that which I use to size the cells appropriately in the view controller:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: (size/3)-8, height: (size/3)-8)
}
```

What is the grey border/shadow, and how can I get rid of it? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is probably just an implementation quirk that appears because you're not quite doing things the way Apple wants. Unless you're subclassing `UIView`, you should call `super.drawRect()` in your own `drawRect()` method. Furthermore, `drawRect()` isn't really the right place to set `cornerRadius`: you should set that once, perhaps when the cell is created, then forget about it.

You might find [Apple's reference for UIView and drawRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html) useful:

> If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation.

One more thing: if you can avoid overriding `drawRect()` you should; it does have a performance impact.

Comment: Thank you TwoStraws - just the advice I need - I swapped the drawRect function for `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    }` and all worked as expected. As Rajan said, you the storyboard method worked too. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest to make a little hack: 
Adding this lines to drawRect

```
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = COLOR_OF_GRPUP_CELL
```

Comment: Thanks Nerowolfe, unfortunately this didn't quite work as hoped. It was better - but there was still a small amount of dark border on the right hand side. It seems the best way to get this to work is to set the value in the storyboard.